# Simperium POST 400 error

Tags: simperium

For some of the managed-objects i am getting following error:

```
****
Simperium POST returned error 400 for change {
    ccid = 94baf4de055140dea4de68710b913779;
    clientid = "ios-b96fa382bbf25166705a25959bc7acbf";
    error = 400;
    id = "New Restaurant Table";
    r =     (
        5040581637a4014af7000000
    );
}
```

It would be really helpful if anyone could please describe why this error occurs. 
Many Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

A 400 response is a catch-all error. Please [contact us](http://simperium.com/contact/) and provide your app ID, a log with verbose logging enabled, and if possible, a screenshot of your Core Data model. If you're seeing any obvious symptoms, for example an object is failing to be created or deleted or updated, please let us know that as well.

Here's a list of error codes for reference:

400 - Catch all error

404 - Missing entity/version

405 - Bad version

409 - Duplicate change

412 - Empty change

413 - Document too large

440 - Invalid diff